# Block countries for payment in Paypal

Tags: paypal, block, paypal-sandbox

I have setup Paypal button on my website and my client want to block payment for some countries. Is there any option??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to not try this in code, just log into your PayPal account and do the following. This will set FOR SURE filters for your account.

Login to your Account.
Click on Profile

Click on My Selling Tools

Under Getting paid and managing my risk

Look for Managing risk and fraud

Click on Update

At the bottom, look for Risk Controls

Check the radio button for Country Monitor

Click on Edit

On the Choose your Countries page

Add the countries you don't want to sell to in the My Monitored Countries

Below check the radio button for Decline

Click on Save

Note, you can also control the dollar amount that you're willing to accept.

Comment: @PankajRawat Please mark my answer as the correct answer for others to see then please.

Comment: Hi, 

Managing risk and fraud Link is not there.